# How do i use ui-sref with multiple parameter

Tags: angularjs, ui-sref

In `ui-sref`, i need to add two states like `ui-sref="form.profile.retail and form.profile.corporate"` , i am not sure how to do this, i have tried using conditional operator but didnt work.

In form.html

```
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="form.profile.retail"><span>2</span> Login</a>
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1J3vskbMEEtiZ8s0mgSA?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-switch` to determine what link to place, I cannot understand your conditional needs so I'll place only an example.

Assign a scope variable like `isRetail` to define when the link should be one or another:

```
<div ng-switch on="isRetail">
   <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="form.profile.retail" ng-switch-when="true">Retail</a>
   <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="form.profile.corporate" ng-switch-default>Corporate</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 ui-sref="form({retail: form.profile.retail, corporate: form.profile.corporate})"
```

You can see this exmaple where multiple params are being passed : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview